# parsing a large json file and retrieving values in python

Tags: python, json

I have one large json file of the format -

```
{
    "x": "",
    "y": {
        "a": {
            "-3": {
                "id": -2,
                "rut": "abc",

            },
            "-1": {
                "id": -1,
                 "rut": "cdf",

             } 
        }
     }
}
```

Now I want to retrieve the values of `id` for all situations.
For this I have the following code -

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('file.json') as data_file:
data = json.load(data_file)
data['y']['a'].value()['id']
```

Since I'm not too familiar with using json in python, I couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong. I used `.value()` because the values `-3` and `-1` could be  **any number**  and are not known before hand. The rest of the values are constant.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Jezor I'm getting an error at .value() as it doesn't seem to be recognized. Not sure how to read values when you don't know a specific attribute name beforehand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import json
from pprint import pprint

```
with open('file.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
    pprint([item['id'] for item in data['y']['a'].values()])
```

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit unclear what your problem/error is, but my gess is that you want to simply iterate over all the available values to get your 'id' fields. It would look something like that:

```
for x in data['y']['a']:
    try:
        print(x['id'])
    except IndexError: #In case 'id' isn't present in that subtree
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use values() ?

However, to get the all 'id's:

```
sub_data = data['y']['a']
for i in sub_data:
    print(sub_data['id'])
```